# SSL termination ElasticBeanstalk Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an application which required https or certain pages.

I am trying to deploy Symfony application using ElasticBeanstalk (EB). EB have this feature where it passes every request http or https request as http to EC2 instance and uses  HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT and HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO to let EC2 instance know what was the original request protocol. As per Symfony documentation I can do something like this.

```
Request::setTrustedProxies(['127.0.0.1', $request->server->get('REMOTE_ADDR')]);
Request::setTrustedHeaderName(Request::HEADER_CLIENT_IP, 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
Request::setTrustedHeaderName(Request::HEADER_CLIENT_HOST, 'HTTP_HOST');
Request::setTrustedHeaderName(Request::HEADER_CLIENT_PORT, 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT');
Request::setTrustedHeaderName(Request::HEADER_CLIENT_PROTO, 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO');
```

and in controller I have defined schemes like this.

```
/**
 *
 * @Route("/products", schemes = { "https" })
 */
 class ProductsController extends Controller
 {
    /**
     * @Route("/{id}", name="show_product", schemes = { "https" })
     * @Method("GET")
     *
     * @return Response A HTTP response
     */
    public function index($id, Request $request)
```

But it is causing never ending loop from https -> http -> https. Is there any way to get around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I posting the solution here so that other can benefit from it. Actually Symfony looks for HTTP header not server header so mapping should be like this.

```
Request::setTrustedHeaderName(Request::HEADER_CLIENT_IP, 'X_FORWARDED_FOR');
Request::setTrustedHeaderName(Request::HEADER_CLIENT_HOST, 'HTTP_HOST');
Request::setTrustedHeaderName(Request::HEADER_CLIENT_PORT, 'X_FORWARDED_PORT');
Request::setTrustedHeaderName(Request::HEADER_CLIENT_PROTO, 'X_FORWARDED_PROTO');
```